# Running webpack configuration sequentially

Tags: webpack, build

I have two configurations for my webpack and I want one to be run only **after another** Is that possible?

I found [this](https://www.viget.com/articles/run-multiple-webpack-configs-sequentially/) but want to know is there a common way than a specific use-case solution?

```
module.exports = [
  {
    ...webpackConfig,
    ...{
      entry: customEntry,
      output: customOutput
    },
    externals
  },
  {
    ...webpackConfig,
    ...{
      entry: entry,
      plugins: enhancedPlugin,
      module: { ...webpackModule, ...{ rules: enhancedRules } }
    }
  }
];
```

What I wanted is to create a library from my app and I don't want to affect the current build system. I know there are other ways but my environment forces me to use: webpack and *It should run sequentially*. :|

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It'll run sequentially by default. I think my issue is with something else. I'll update this answer if I get more info. From docs:

> Multiple configurations will not be run in parallel. Each configuration is only processed after the previous one has finished processing. To process them in parallel, you can use a third-party solution like parallel-webpack.

Answer (score 0):

You can use webpack MultiCompiler node api, for sequentially compilation.
docs: https://webpack.js.org/api/node/#multicompiler